# ListView scrollbar behaviour

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8

Typically when moving the scrollbar to the middle of a scrollable window, the text position  will be static, even when appending more text at the bottom; instead the scrollbar´s cursor slowly moves up.
ListView shows the contrary behaviour: With the scrollbar´s cursor positioned somewhere in the middle it keeps its position, while the text moves up. See example program:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListViewTest extends Application  {

    ListView<String> listview= new ListView<String>();
    private ObservableList<String> items =FXCollections.observableArrayList ();

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        listview.setItems(items);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());
        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(listview);
        ((StackPane) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setHeight(200);
        stage.show();

        Task<Integer> testTask = new Task<Integer>() {
            @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                try {Thread.sleep(500);} catch (InterruptedException e) {   }
                for (int i=0;i<50;i++) {
                    try {Thread.sleep(300);} catch (InterruptedException e) {   }
                    final int j=i;
                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            items.add(""+j);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return 0;
            }
        };
        new Thread(testTask).start();
    }
}
```

Can this be stopped/changed? Or maybe how can I determine the item number currently visible at topmost position? Then scrollTo() could be used to keep the position.

Comment: I´ll give the user a way to suspend and resume updates, so the ListView doesn´t move when browsing through the messages. (I would still prefer if s.o. came up with a better solution)